# Negate git pathspec - match all files except one directory

Tags: git

I'm moving/merging several existing repositories into one (they are all used to build the same monolithic app). Some of those had several dead projects in them, and I only need a single directory from the whole repo.

I'm looking for `git rm` pathspec syntax (for rewriting the repo history) that will remove all files except those in `SomeSampleDirectory`.

So, essentially, a negation of:

```
git filter-branch -f 
    --prune-empty 
    --index-filter 
    "git rm --cached -f --ignore-unmatch SomeSampleDirectory/*" 
    --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need someting along the line of :

```
ls | grep -v SomeSampleDirectory | xargs git rm --cached -f
```

`ls` would not work with a `--index-filter`, as the content will not be on disk.

One way to view the flat list of files/dirs for the active commit at the root directory of the repo is :

```
$ git show HEAD^{tree}
tree HEAD^{tree}

.gitattributes
.gitignore
.mailmap
  ...
```

You can drop the 2 leading lines of the output with `tail -n +3`

So you can drop "everything but SomeSampleDirectory" using :

```
git show HEAD^{tree} | tail -n +3 | grep -v SomeSampleDirectory |
    xargs git rm --cached -f
```

as the command to apply on each commit.

---

*Note :* obsviously, if for some reason you also need to keep some other files (`.gitattributes`, `.gitignore`, ...) you can add some extra `grep -v foobar` along the way.